# Finding SQL records referenced by another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, *Products* and *Stock*. *Stock* has many to one relation with *Products*.
The *Stock* table references the *Products* table.
I want to find all products where at least one referencing stock has a quantity that is greater than 0.

What is the most efficient query I should use?

*Stock*: id(bigint), quantity(bigint), product_id(varchar)

Thanks

Comment: you need to *join* the tables, but it's difficult to give details without more information: edit your question to give the names of at least the most important columns, and the primary keys.

Comment: Kindly use the answer i posted.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first join the two tables. This will return a new table with the all the stock records and their product details on the condition that the quantity is grater than zero.
Then because a product can be referenced by multiple stock records, we perform the grouping.

see [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

try this:

```
SELECT product.* FROM product INNER JOIN stock ON product.id = stock.product_id AND stock.quantity > 0 GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
SELECT p.product_id,s.quantity FROM dbo.Products p INNER JOIN dbo.Stock  s 
ON s.product_id= p.product_id GROUP BY p.product_id,s.quantity HAVING s.quantity>0
```

Answer (score -1):

without having clouse

> select p.* from stock s  join products p on p.id = s.pid

Comment: This is not sufficient, you skipped the part related to quantity.

Comment: i assume there is not zero valued records in stock